# send a canvas image to server format JPG javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It is posible to send a canvas image to server format JPG?
I tried with var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg') but did not work.
Can someone help me please?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to convert your image to base64 format using Javascript:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var data = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
```

And send this data to your PHP server using ajax for example. Then, in your PHP file, you just have to use this code to convert the base64 data to an image:

```
file_put_contents("myimage.jpg", base64_decode(explode(",", $_GET['data'])[1]));
```

That's all !

Comment: Thanks Lucas,I've already done that, but I want JPG format send to server.. is not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you wanted the JPEG format. I updated my answer.

Comment: Perhaps you should remove the heading 'data:image/jpeg,' on either side

Comment: If my answer could help you, you can validate it.